# Creating and Populating a Porperty Grid - Iron Python

Tags: python, .net, propertygrid

I am creating an Iron Python application that reads settings from an xml. It will also allow the user to saves out settings to an xml file.

I have to use Iron Python. I looked and tried to use the DataGridView to accomplish this, but I think the Property Grid is my best option (please let me know if there is a better way to create a simple settings table).

I added the property grid to the form, and now I do not know how to add the data to it. I tried using this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx

However, that is in C#. I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
class MainForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.InitializeComponent()
        appset = AppSettings();
        self._propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = appset

    def InitializeComponent(self):
        self._propertyGrid1 = System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid()

class AppSettings(self):
    def __init__(self):
        saveOnClose = True
    def saveOnClose(self):
        return self.saveOnClose
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized I was doing something dumb.

```
class MainForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.InitializeComponent()
        appset = AppSettings();
        self._propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = appset

    def InitializeComponent(self):
        self._propertyGrid1 = System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid()

class AppSettings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.saveOnClose = True
    def saveOnClose(self):
        return self.saveOnClose
```